# When using DISTINCT the COUNT (*) OVER() does not return the correct number

Tags: postgresql

I had a similar question to this, but this time I use a more complex query to describe my problem...

I'm just wondering if there is an easy way to get a distinct count when selecting a joined multiple rows query in Postgresql (I am using limit and offset for pagination, but maybe it's not too important in this case).

For example, I have these tables

student table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Student1 |
| 2 | Student2 |
| 3 | Student3 |

teacher table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Teacher1 |
| 1 | Teacher2 |

student_teacher table:

| id | studentId | teacherId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 |

classroom table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Classroom1 |
| 2 | Classroom2 |
| 3 | Classroom3 |

teacher_classoom table:

| id | teacherId | classroomId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |

Here is my current sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(student.*), COUNT(*) OVER() AS "total_count" from student
JOIN student_teacher on student_teacher.studentId = student.id
JOIN teacher on student_teacher.teacherId = teacher.id
JOIN teacher_classroom on teacher_classroom.teacherId = teacher.id
JOIN classroom on classroom.id = teacher_classroom.classroomId 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The "total_count" would be 9 instead of 3 (the number of distinct student after the join query) even though the result only have 3 rows. Without the "distinct" keyword, the result has 9 rows.

Is there an easy way to achieve the total_count = 3? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: An easy way to achieve what? Do you want `total_count` to be 3, not 9? Please state clearly what you are after. The clearest way to do this is post the dataset you are getting now, and the dataset that you want.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, achieve total_count = 3.. I have edited the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is calculated *after* window functions, so you have to use a subquery:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS "total_count"
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT student.*
      from student
         JOIN student_teacher on student_teacher.studentId = student.id
         JOIN teacher on student_teacher.teacherId = teacher.id
         JOIN teacher_classroom on teacher_classroom.teacherId = teacher.id
         JOIN classroom on classroom.id = teacher_classroom.classroomId
    ) AS subq
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

It would be more efficient to turn the inner joins and the `DISTINCT` into a series of `EXISTS` conditions.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do.. I do not realise that distinct is done after the window function.. I think using subquery should be fine for now.. thanks for your help

Comment: apparently for a more complex query which fetches a lot of data, using subquery is pretty slow... do you think using EXISTS will improve the performance? At the moment I am using a generic function which basically do SELECT *, COUNT( * ) OVER() AS "total_count" FROM (`${sql}`) AS subq LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;

Comment: The join and the `DISTINCT` in your query are only used to check if there exist rows in the other tables that match a student. `EXISTS` will be more efficient, particularly because `DISTINCT` is expensive.